# hibernate map mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, pojo

i write pojo that map to mysql table with hibernate,but i do not want to bind a pojo attribute to mysql table field.
that code is blow:

```
public class User{

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String donotBindAttribute;
    set get......
}
```

how to do not bind attribue "donotBindAttribute" to mysql field
who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use as follows -

```
@Transient
private String donotBindAttribute;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make this variable transient.

If you use JPA annotations, then [@Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) is way to go. If you use hbm.xml, simply don't map field and it will not be considered as persistent attribute.

Comment: Ignoring an attribute that I do not want to map by excluding from hbm.xml has worked for me. Also, Ignoring tables(non related) from cfg.xml also helps a lot on the load.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Transient
private String donotBindAttribute;
```

Make it Transient.

*Assuming you are using JPA.